# PHP MYSQL LIMIT Error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running php code over ibm i series server.

I've been trying to limit the number of records i'm getting using LIMIT.
I used this query (which works just fine without "LIMIT") :

```
$query="SELECT slgrpn,slfrkn,slftyp,slfsze,slpqty,slpwht,slentp,slqplt,sltots,slfrmn,slcstn,sldtrd FROM HUTAYOSI.$file ORDER BY slcstn ASC LIMIT 10";
```

And I got this error:

```
Token LIMIT was not valid. Valid tokens: FOR USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH OPTIMIZE.
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried without the order by clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your using DB2. For this you will have to use `FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY` instead of `LIMIT 10`

so your query will look like this:

```
$query="SELECT slgrpn,slfrkn,slftyp,slfsze,slpqty,slpwht,slentp,slqplt,sltots,slfrmn,slcstn,sldtrd FROM HUTAYOSI.$file ORDER BY slcstn FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY";
```

Best regards
Jonas

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are connecting to a MySQL database? Your error message looks like it is comming from a DB2 database.

If your database is DB2 then to limit the result set being returned, MySQL uses the keyword, LIMIT, while DB2 Express uses FETCH FIRST n ROWS to limit the result set being returned.

And as such your query should look like this:

```
$query="SELECT slgrpn,slfrkn,slftyp,slfsze,slpqty,slpwht,slentp,slqplt,sltots,slfrmn,slcstn,sldtrd FROM HUTAYOSI.$file ORDER BY slcstn FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY";
```